# AWS Amplify No Option to Add Environment Variables

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm currently building a React app with AWS Amplify and in the backend, I have to connect to an API with an API key. I understand that the best practice is to hide the keys in a dotenv file or set the environment variables. I looked online that for AWS Amplify, there should be an option to edit the Environment Variables in the Amplify Console. However, I do not see that option. How can I add environment variables to my amplify-react app in this case?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html .
does this help ?

Answer (score 0):

My console shows this. Is yours missing this Environment Variables command?
[image: Amplify Console]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html

[image]

So I removed the environments and re-set them up for auto deploy and re-deployed them. now the environment variables items show up.